# stop vue js watch property from watching sub objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi this is my code,

```
        var vm = new Vue({
                el: '#el',
                data: {
                    input: {
                        sorting: "",
                        brand: null,
                        model: null,
                        country: "all",
                        cap: "",
                        radius: ""         
                    }
                },
                watch: {
                    input: {
                        handler(newInput) {

                        },
                        deep: true
                    }  
                }
            });
```

Here I'm watching weather input object changes. But I need to watch only some items only input object. For example **I need to do something if input.country changes but not when input.brand changes.** Unfortunately my code is complex and can't take items out of input object.

Answer (score 0):

Just watch what you need:

```
            watch: {
                'input.country': {
                    handler(newCountry) {

                    }
                }  
            }
```

Comment: unfortunately I cant do that since there are lots of items

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `computed` value who target `this.item.country`:

```
computed: {
    itemCountry() {
        return this.item.country;
    }
}
```

And watch this new computed value:

```
watch: {
    itemCountry: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(newInput) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```